Purification and taharah
I have a problem while moving, sitting in ground and walking.
While iam do some movement,one sid of my penis tip touches the clothes inside and  other opens up at mouth and the inside skin of penis tip touches the cloth, as we know there is no urine but the dampness of urine is there, i suffer from washing again and again whenever the tip rubbed and opens up snd dampness of the tip of urine touches touches the cloth, also i have OCD,
And iam sure that one side of my tip during movement opens up and dampness may be touched cloth(hardship for cleaning multiple times)
